# MySQL speed up data migration

Tags: mysql

I need to migrate data from 20 tables to one table. The legacy code needs to be updated, where in the past a product was stored in a table called `p_<productgroup_name>`, we are now storing everything in one table called `product`. and the product group where the product is in is in a related table. I know, this should have been done from the starting, but it is legacy and we need to continue.

So I need to migrate from 20 tabels to 1 table, in total the `product` table will have ~50.000 records. But because each product gets a new product ID, I need to update all related tables to. This is around 40 tables that need to be updated. But this is going very very slow, and during the migration, the webshop can't be used because all product ID's are being updated.

What is the best way to speed this up? Lock the whole database and put the webshop down for e.g. 30 minutes (wouldn't be a problem in the middle of the night).

Comment: I would test this in dev before production a) to see that nothing breaks and b) to get indicative timings.

Comment: @P.Salmon, I do that. And on my dev environment one update query takes 300ms, and I need to do that 50.000 times. And that is only one of the 42 tables.